# Firstname or lastname case change query without unintended consequences.

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I am running the query below in Sybase application which works great but the consequences are when the first name is written like this, "ADNAN RAZA" it makes it "Adnan raza". Any function which I can use here to detect the position of letter after space or - and update. Can't do it manually there are more than 100k records.

```
update master set firstname = 
upper(left(firstname,1))+lower(substr(firstname,2));
```

Comment: This is really more of a presentation issue which should be handled in application code rather than actually modifying your database.

Comment: Unfortunately, application is pre written and I cannot modify it, otherwise it would be too easy :)

Comment: Is this a one-time thing or will you have to do this often?

Comment: I will have to do it quite often.

Comment: If you can do it in app code (like java, perl, even shell script) your life will probably be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for this at db level as it stands now.

Answer (score 1):

in Oracle SQL there is a function called initcap (character-expression).
 
Initcap returns character- expression with each word's first character in uppercase and the rest in lowercase.
i saw somewhere that in Sybase you have dbo.intcap(name) for this.

Comment: dba.intcap is a user defined function not a built in one and it is using the same logic as I have already posted in my question so problem remains the same. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: hi<br/>there is a code example here that might help [link](http://www.novicksoftware.com/UDFofWeek/Vol1/T-SQL-UDF-Volume-1-Number-47-proper-case.htm)